# multipath equivalent that doesn't require root privilege

Tags: linux, non-root-user, storage, multipath-storage

Is there any native tool that can show multipath topology but doesn't need root privileges? Basically the same output as `multipath -ll`

Comment: Why not just add a sudo rule permitting non-root to run `multipath -ll` ?